# MySQL: How to count rows when multiple joined tables?

Tags: mysql

```
MySQL: How to count rows when multiple joined tables ??

+Query:

    SELECT p.role FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id=u.role 
    INNER JOIN permissions p ON p.role=r.id 
    WHERE p.p_id=19 AND p.p_update=1 AND r.active=1 
    GROUP BY p.role

+Result:

    ________
    |p_role:|
    |_______|
    |   1   |
    |   4   |
    |_______|

When I add COUNT() function to p.role:

+Query:

    SELECT COUNT(p.role) FROM users u 
    INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id=u.role 
    INNER JOIN permissions p ON p.role=r.id 
    WHERE p.p_id=19 AND p.p_update=1 AND r.active=1 
    GROUP BY p.role

+Result:

    _______________
    |COUNT(p_role):|
    |______________|
    |      5       |
    |      1       |
    |______________|

Why I see 2 records I already use COUNT() function??
I don't want to see result like this.
I want to count rows of query above.

I want to see result like this:

    _______________
    |COUNT(p_role):|
    |______________|
    |      2       |
    |______________|

Please anyone help me. Thanks in advance!
Sorry for my broken English.
```

Comment: And the result should be?

Comment: It worked. SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(p.role)) FROM users u 
INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id=u.role 
INNER JOIN permissions p ON p.role=r.id 
WHERE p.p_id=19 AND p.p_update=1 AND r.active=1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `GROUP BY` clause in your query, it returns count per `p.role` value. If you want the query to return one value, you can remove `GROUP BY`, e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(p.role)) FROM users u 
INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id=u.role 
INNER JOIN permissions p ON p.role=r.id 
WHERE p.p_id=19 AND p.p_update=1 AND r.active=1;
```

By the way, I have added `DISTINCT` to the query so that it will return count of distinct `p.role` values. If you want the count of records only, you can remove `DISTINCT`.